integral of sine with an infinitely small period
The problem is:
Suppose that $f$ is a positive function such that $f'$ is continuous. Using integration by parts, confirm the guess that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x)\sin{nx} \, dx = 0.$$
Hint: since $f'$ is continuous, there is a constant M such that $|f'(x)| \le M$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.
My solution do this is:
Take $f(x)$ as the $u$ and $\sin{nx}$ as the $v'$, then we have,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x) \, \sin{nx} \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\left[-\frac{1}{n}\cos{nx}f(x)\right]_0^1 + \int_0^1 \frac{1}{n} \cos{nx} f'(x) \, dx \right).$$
Here comes a step that im not sure about, i directly evaluated the first term on the RHS as 0, because of the $1/n$, is that valid? Does the fact that $f'$ is continuous mean that $f'$ is bounded within $[0,1]$?
After this, I applied the hint:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} -\frac{M}{n} \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{n} \, \cos{nx} f'(x) \, dx \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{M}{n}$$
Both sides converge to 0, and so, we obtain the final result of
$$lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x) \, \sin{nx} \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{n} \, \cos{nx} f'(x) \, dx = 0.$$
I'm very unsure about my steps... thanks in advance :)

$f$ is differentiable, hence continuous, hence also bounded in $0\le x \le 1$.

A continuous function on a compact interval (ie $[0,1]$) is bounded

Oh ok thanks i see then :)

It doesn't matter for $$\left[-\frac{1}{n}\cos{nx}f(x)\right]_0^1 = \frac{f(0) - f(1)\cos n}n$$ how $f$ behaves. As long as $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are defined, the limit as $n \to \infty$ is $0$.
